# How can I set up Eclipse to work with a Quickly program?

Tags: python, quickly, eclipse, ide

I've installed PyDev in Eclipse and have configured my project so that the project lies under `Workspace/Eclipse` and the Quickly files lies under `Workspace/Quickly`. To connect the two I've linked the Quickly project by creating a new folder in Eclipse under the project and select the "advanced option" in the dialog to link a folder into the project. That way I don't need to have the Eclipse project files in my Quickly project.

But there is two issues that arises for me:

1. In Eclipse I have to select a Python interpreter and I have no idea what to do. I've googled around for an answer but I can't find if Quickly uses Python 3 or 2.7. Can someone help me make an informed choice? (I'm new to developing Python, that's why I can't tell the difference by the syntax - if there even is a difference)
2. I can't press the "Run" button to launch the application. Must I initialize a program with `quickly run`? I want to be able to debug through Eclipse, how do I configure this?

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS and the Eclipse version from the repositories.

Comment: The question is about the Ubuntu app development framework called Quickly, not regarding the speed of Eclipse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I to got interested in this after seeing your question, after a bit of goggling with out any interesting results I decided to try my self and see if i could figure something out. This is more of a workaround then an actual solution.

I started by creating a test project using quickly:

```
quickly create ubuntu-application foo
```

Then i launched eclipse and created a new python project and imported the quickly project folder. Right-cklick on project->import
[image: Import quickly folder][image: Import quickly folder]

Then I added the quickly-project path to the eclipse project: Right-click on project->properties

go to PyDev - PYTHONPATH-> add source folder, and select the root map of quickly project

*(This is not necessary but it removes those annoying read markings that complains about not finding imports)*
[image: Add to path][image: Add to path]

So now the only thing left is to be able to launch the project from eclipse. To do that click on the run-menu at the top of eclipse->External tools->External tools configuration

Right-click Program and select "New" Name it something like Run

1. For location enter the path to quickly executeble (/usr/bin/quickly)
2. For working directory click on "browse workspace" and select the root foolder of the quickly project
3. For arguments typ run
4. Go to the tab common and under "Display in favorite menu" select External Tools

Create a new one and name it something like design, the only thing to change in this one would be to type "design" instead of "run" under argument.

Now you can Run or launch glade to change design from the dropdown menu I'm trying to show on the last picture.

[image: Setup run][image: Setup run][image: Setup run]

For the python question I would suggest that use Python3 because Ubuntu is aiming to only include python3 in Ubuntu 12.10 and forward. (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Python/3)

As for setting up python in eclipse: when you create a new pydev project, you should see an option to select python grammar version and interpreter. If you cant find the right python version under interpreter click on "Click here to configure an interpeter not listed"

In the new window click new and give it a name, then click on browse to /usr/bin and select the python version you like to add for example python3.2mu, then click apply and ok. now you should be able to select that version from the create new project window
[image][image][image]

Hope this helps you

Comment: Wow! Thanks for an excellent guide! You even provided tips on how to make things even better (quickly design)! I'd also hoped to get an explanation of the "python interpreter". Do you know anything regarding that? If not I'll probably give you the bounty anyway but if you do know something about it, can you please elaborate the answer further with an answer to that as well? :)

Comment: How should I set up the interpreter? I haven't fully grasped that. I've only used Eclipse earlier for web development.

Comment: I've also added quickly project root folder to the PYTHONPATH though I still get "import unresolved" for Gtk and some other...

Comment: Sorry I didn't get that, I'm not sure what you mean but i have updated my answer to include python setup. Yeah i get that to, I don't know why but i found this http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3316325&group_id=85796&atid=577329 look at the last comment.

Comment: Thanks! It got fixed by adding "gi" to "forced built-ins" under the selected interpreter. This page taught me everything I needed to know about the interpreter (it was linked at the sourceforge page): http://pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html#PyDevInterpreterConfiguration-PredefinedCompletions